# Did a British civilian row across the channel and shoot 6 Luftwaffe pilots?

Tags: world-war-two, germany, great-britain

As we were studying WWII, our history teacher told us a story that, to me at least, seemed apocryphal. But given that she didn't provide any citations, I was unable to confirm our falsify her story. So I'm turning to H.SE for help here.

Recounted, the story went something like this: A British man heard that some Luftwaffe were bragging about bombing London (this was amidst the siege of Britain made by Germany during WWII). This enraged the man so much that he rowed across the English channel, went to the bar in France which these Luftwaffe men frequented, shot 6 of the Luftwaffe men, and rowed back across the channel.

Any citation, Wikipedia article, or further reading so I can confirm this story and learn more are greatly appreciated. Blessings!

Comment: Not clear to me how he heard that the Luftwaffe were bragging.  Pretty keen ears if he can hear the Luftwaffe in a French pub, or perhaps in bombers in flight....  Seems quite implausible.

Comment: Not to mention that the English channel is 21 miles across at its narrowest, so a round trip would be at least 42 miles. Not something that just anyone could manage (even on a good day without the wartime naval patrols) so presumably this chap was a keen rower prior to his exploit. Were the 6 Luftwaffe men meant to be those responsible for the bragging? If so, who located them and identified them to the British civilian?

Comment: The 'bragging' could have been Nazi propaganda broadcasts - Lord Haw Haw crowing over the destruction the Luftwaffe had visited on British cities. Just about plausible that someone would hear that and want to get their hands on Luftwaffe men and kill them.

Comment: @NeMo Or the **Ghost of Christmas Past** whispered it into his ear after one pint to many... The OP is asking for possible facts, not speculations.

Comment: Actually - I was just assuming that he got told it by someone - perhaps someone who frequented France. Not a mysterious voice.

Comment: @LukeHill After Dunkirk, all communication between France and the UK were cut. It is claimed that this also effected german spies in Britian, which is a sign that they hadn't expected this situation to arise.

Comment: @MarkJohnson There's no need to be sarcastic. Someone questioned how anyone in Britain could have heard about Luftwaffe bragging - if you look up Lord Haw Haw, it is a fact that his broadcasts were widely heard. In other words, the idea that a British civilian was incensed by Luftwaffe bragging is not the implausible part of the story.

Comment: If the Luftwaffe base had a bar, should have been a rather large one.

Comment: Lord Haw-Haw was [dealt with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Joyce) but not by shooting.

Comment: @SteveBird People *swim* across the channel. So rowing across it is not ridiculous at all for a motivated and physically fit person. I agree that getting past the naval patrols (on both sides!) would be a bit of a tall order, but again this isn't the most unbelievable part of the story.

Comment: @NeMo Those that swim, don't do so alone. They are accompanied by another boat to insure that they don't drift south due to the strong currents at the Strait of Dover. The further they drift south, the futher the coast line is away. It's the most unrealistic part of the story.

Comment: *One-way* Channel crossings by manually-propelled vessels did indeed happen during WW2. It was an extremely risky undertaking. From the [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-suffolk-57205877): "World War Two: The brothers who fled Nazi occupation by kayak [...] Of the 32 men known to have tried to kayak from the Netherlands to England during the war, the Peteri brothers were among just eight who survived."

Comment: @NeMo: If you're willing to row at night (assuming you have a way to navigate without turning on any lights) you probably will get past the naval patrols.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "Technically, Joyce was hanged for making a false statement when applying for a passport, the usual penalty for which is a small fine."

Comment: @Andy - Joyce was convicted of one count of high treason at the Old Bailey; that remark about the 'false statement' was AJP Taylor's interpretation of what has been called 'legalised murder'.

Comment: @Andy [PDF: British Nationality and Status of Aliens Act, 1914](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1914/17/pdfs/ukpga_19140017_en.pdf): *The following persons shall be deemed to Definition of
be **natural-born British subjects**, namely:- Any person born out of His Majesty's dominions **whose father was, at the time of that person's birth**, a British subject, and who fulfils any
of the following conditions, that is to say, if
either- (i) **his father was born within His Majesty's allegiance** ; or...*

Comment: @Andy It has never been claimed that the father renounced his UK citizenship, so William Joyce was (and was treated as) a **natural-born British subject** at birth. Since the family returned around 1910/12, the father would have lost his US citizenship 2 years after returning.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> A British man heard that some Luftwaffe were bragging about bombing London (this was amidst the siege of Britain made by Germany during WWII). This enraged the man so much that he rowed across the English channel, went to the bar in France which these Luftwaffe men frequented, shot 6 of the Luftwaffe men, and rowed back across the channel.

As the second map shows, bombers were not stationed near the coast.

There were fighter bases east of Calais, but the likelihood of their crews being anywhere near the beaches in a bar is zero.

That, of course, assumes that the rowing boat actually arrives anywhere near Calais since the currents at the Strait of Dover are extremely strong.

I think your history teacher should have a long talk with your geography teacher.

| Situation Maps August 1940 |
| --- |
| [image] |
| [image] |

---

Maybe you should advise your history teacher to try to sell that story plot to some Hollywood producer who specializes in tall stories from alternative realities.

Comment: Michael Bay's ***ROWBOAT*** Also somehow the guy is American.

Comment: @Schwern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Men_Went_to_War (from David Lawson's answer)

Answer (score 31):

This sounds a bit like an embellished version of the story of Peter King

> "King joined the Dental Corps in March 1939 and served as a non-technician, excelling as a weapons instructor. He spent two years in this role, rapidly becoming a drill sergeant at the Dental Corps' depot, but then applied to transfer to a fighting unit. This was refused. King was so frustrated that he and another soldier, Pte Leslie Cuthbertson, then 20 and from Newcastle-upon-Tyne took matters in their own hands; they planned and executed an unofficial and unauthorised raid on occupied France." *[Wikipedia:Peter_King_(British_Army_officer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_King_(British_Army_officer))*

Comment: In the Peter King story, it seems he did not hear the Luftwaffe bragging, he and Leslie Cuthbertson stole a motor-boat i.e. did not row, tried to damage a French railway line with a grenade (in the comedy film they attacked a radar station cookhouse thinking it was the operations room) rather than shooting pilots, but still a surprising amateur commando raid.

Comment: The Rowing bit does sound like the Cockleshell heroes, but that was launched from a submarine, and wasn't a private venture

Comment: A drill sergeant in the Dental Corps? I see what you did there.

Comment: My favorite part of the story is that they didn't return home in the same motor boat they stole to get to France, but rather stole *another* boat in France for the return trip...

Comment: I found an article about them with photos of both men. Cuthbertson later became Deputy Lord Mayor of Newcastle. http://www.nortonofmorton.com/2016/05/mad-dogs-and-servicemen-sergeant-king.html

Comment: Did no-one notice how confused that Peter_King_ link is?